# Redirect port without opening it

Tags: iptables

I have the following iptables configuration

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 10001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10001
```

But I don't want to have port 10001 opened, that's the reason why I'm doing the redirect (and that I don't want to run my server as root), right?

But if I remove the third line, the forwarding stops working.

So any idea how to redirect the port without opening it to the world?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that eth0 is your public interface and that you don't wish your SSL web server to be visible to the public.

I think you should rather restrict who can connect to the port instead of trying to hide it.

One solution without using routing would be to set your web server (apache2?) to only bind to your loopback device (lo, 127.0.0.1) for SSL. This assumes you connect to your web server only from the computer where the webserver is running.

Another method would be to add to your iptables the ability to accept anything on lo, and refuse if port 443 on eth0 (via default policy)

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p TCP -j ACCEPT
```

If you need to connect remotely to the web server, and you have static IP address, you can always only accept incoming connections to 443 from only that IP.

Another method I can think of to hide your port 443 from the exterior would be using port knocking.

Other methods do exist (within apache2) to prevent/accept connections to the server from specific IPs.